# How do I retrieve the user's given and family name from Microsoft with OpenIdConnect?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, abp

I have an Asp Boilerplate (ABP) application. I have set up OpenIdConnect to log in with a Microsoft account, and have been able to successfully log in while running the application locally. However, I cannot then see my first or last name while debugging the application.

Here is my method to configure the Authentication

```
private static void ConfigureAuthentication(ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    context.Services.ForwardIdentityAuthenticationForBearer(OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    context.Services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"), cookieScheme: null);

    context.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"] + "/v2.0/";
        options.ClientId = configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
        options.CallbackPath = configuration["AzureAd:CallbackPath"];
        options.ClientSecret = configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveTokens = false;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub");
        options.Scope.Add("user.read");
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");

        // Map first and last name claims
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");
        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_name");
    });
}
```

I expect to be able to see my first and last name when I debug and inspect the resulting claims principal, however I do not have that claim.

Here are the configured permissions for the AppRegistration

[image]

and here is the token configuration

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your backend needs to use the [On Behalf of Flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) to enable this. To see what this looks like, see steps 14 and 15 of my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/azure-ad-troubleshooting/).

**EXAMPLE CODE**

I have done this work in Node.js in the past, and this was the code I used. You would need to translate it to C#:

```js
    /*
     * Return Graph user info claims
     */
    public async getUserInfo(accessToken: string): Promise<UserInfoClaims> {

        // We need to get a separate Graph API token to get user info
        const userInfoAccessToken = await this._getGraphAccessToken(accessToken);

        // Next look up user info and get claims
        return this._getUserInfoClaims(userInfoAccessToken);
    }

    /*
     * Use a user assertion to get a different token for the same user, with permissions to call the user info endpoint
     */
    private async _getGraphAccessToken(accessToken: string): Promise<string> {

        try {

            const formData = new URLSearchParams();
            formData.append('grant_type', 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer');
            formData.append('client_id', this._configuration.graphClient.clientId);
            formData.append('client_secret', this._configuration.graphClient.clientSecret);
            formData.append('assertion', accessToken);
            formData.append('scope', this._configuration.graphClient.scope);
            formData.append('requested_token_use', 'on_behalf_of');

            const options = {
                url: this._configuration.tokenEndpoint,
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'accept': 'application/json',
                },
                httpsAgent: this._httpProxy.agent,
            };

            const response = await axios.request(options as AxiosRequestConfig) as any;
            return response.data.access_token!;

        } catch (e: any) {

            // Report Graph errors clearly
            throw ErrorFactory.fromUserInfoTokenGrantError(e, this._configuration.tokenEndpoint);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Perform OAuth user info lookup when required
     */
    private async _getUserInfoClaims(accessToken: string): Promise<UserInfoClaims> {

        try {

            const options = {
                url: this._configuration.userInfoEndpoint,
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                },
                httpsAgent: this._httpProxy.agent,
            };

            const response = await axios.request(options as AxiosRequestConfig);
            const userInfo = response.data as any;

            // In my simple setup focused on developer convenience, the email is in the name setting
            const givenName = ClaimsReader.getClaim(userInfo.given_name, 'given_name');
            const familyName = ClaimsReader.getClaim(userInfo.family_name, 'family_name');
            const email = ClaimsReader.getClaim(userInfo.name, 'name');
            return new UserInfoClaims(givenName, familyName, email);

        } catch (e: any) {

            // Report user info errors clearly
            throw ErrorFactory.fromUserInfoError(e, this._configuration.userInfoEndpoint);
        }
    }
```